# JQuery Draggable in FireFox only works in iFrame - How to set ViewPort

Tags: jquery, css, viewport, jquery-ui-draggable

Testing jQuery UI Draggable in FireFox 33.0.2 : I copied the code from the example, and it simply doesn't work. The scripts are working, css classes added, event bindings added, etc. Simply won't drag.

If I put the page inside an iFrame, it works. Is this a ViewPort problem?

**DOESN'T WORK:**

Their page outside the iFrame won't work: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/draggable/default.html

**WORKS:**

Put the same page inside an iFrame, and it works:

```
<iframe
    style="height: 400px;width: 400px;"
    src="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/draggable/default.html"
    >
</iframe>
```

I have tried to wrap it in a large div with relative positioning. I tried setting meta viewpoint. No go. Chrome seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was with FireFox 33.0.2. Slider also wasn't working. Updated to 33.0.3, and all is well.